# bs4 and request for webscraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

mrs, my object is get thee value in a site. I started the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as rq

url = """https://www.pontofrio.com.br/Eletrodomesticos/GeladeiraeRefrigerador/2Portas/refrigerador-consul-crm43nb-frost-free-branco-386-l-9600908.html?recsource=busca-int&rectype=busca-14"""    

soup = bs(rq.get(url).text, "html.parser")  #html.parser é se nao, uma configuração do construtor bs4.

print(soup)
```

But the result is a error :/
In line 8 we have the value "1880.05". I think way is get a chain of link in:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> { "@context": "http://schema.org/", "@type": "Product",  "name": "Refrigerador Consul CRM43NB Frost Free Branco - 386 L ", "offers": { "@type": "Offer", "priceCurrency": "BRL", "availability": "InStock", "price": "1880.05" } } </script>
```

for get the value, but i found dificults :/

The error is:

> > > %Run cod_vic.py
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
> > >           chunked=chunked,
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
> > >           six.raise_from(e, None)
> > >         File "", line 3, in raise_from
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
> > >           httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1336, in getresponse
> > >           response.begin()
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
> > >           version, status, reason = self._read_status()
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 267, in _read_status
> > >           line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
> > >           return self._sock.recv_into(b)
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
> > >           return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
> > >         File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
> > >           return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
> > >       TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu

corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou

porque o host conectado não respondeu

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1336, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu\r\ncorretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou\r\nporque o host conectado não respondeu', None, 10060, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\aula1\cod_vic.py", line 6, in 
    soup = bs(rq.get(url).text, "html.parser")  #html.parser é se nao, uma configuração do construtor bs4.
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu\r\ncorretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou\r\nporque o host conectado não respondeu', None, 10060, None))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they're checking the [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent). There are already plenty of solid resources on the subject, so I won't cover anything more here. I used my browser's current User-Agent, which you can easily find [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) or through your browser's tools/settings.

I tweaked your code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pontofrio.com.br/Eletrodomesticos/Geladeirae" \
      "Refrigerador/2Portas/refrigerador-consul-crm43nb-frost-free-branco-386-l-9600908.html"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")  # Use .content, not .text, when passing the data to BeautifulSoup

with open('../out/temp.html', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: well, in my case the user agent is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36

ok, perfect.

I change of your code but the error continue:

Comment: @Tsutsui Great, so using that should solve the issue!

Comment: url = """https://www.pontofrio.com.br/Eletrodomesticos/GeladeiraeRefrigerador/2Portas/refrigerador-consul-crm43nb-frost-free-branco-386-l-9600908.html?recsource=busca-int&rectype=busca-14"""    

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")  # Use .content, not .text, when passing the data to BeautifulSoup

with open('../out/temp.html', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(soup.prettify())

Comment: >>> %Run cod_vic.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\aula1\cod_vic.py", line 11, in <module>
    with open('../out/temp.html', 'w') as out_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../out/temp.html'

Comment: @Tsutsui That's a non-issue, it's just that the path refers to a folder on my computer which you obviously don't have.

Comment: your space in the sky was reserved :)

Comment: @Tsutsui Problem solved, then? Do you have any questions?

Comment: hm :/ i don't find the price.
The begin of answer is:
"                                   Características Gerais 
                                </dt>
<dd>
<br/>- Função Turbo (freezer e refrigerador)"

This is ref in the middle of the site. How can i get the price? I know that this information be in superior (up) the page.

Comment: @Tsutsui Ah, well that's a different question entirely. If you have no experience with web scraping, you should look at some guides or tutorials.